# What specifically the meaning of "Error Code 403 ASN mismatch"?

Tags: php, json, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm trying to create an application that uses the Streamtape API (https://streamtape.com/api#download-getlink) to download a video file. My application run smoothly and perfectly on local development server. However, when I deployed it to live server (AWS), I'm getting a 403 error saying "`ASN mismatch / Website: AS14618 Download: AS9299`".

I'm trying to figure out the cause of it but no luck. Any idea or fix? I'm using `file_get_contents` to get te data from JSON response and dynamically add it to  link.

Comment: ASN mismatch, means AS14618 !== AS9299

Comment: At it's core it would seem a permission issue. Need more detail I think to be able to try and provide a solution.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone yeah but what's possibly the cause?

Comment: @RaffyM avent a clue don't use aws, too expensive

Comment: @ficuscr as the instruction from the API documentation here: https://streamtape.com/api, I need to get a Download Ticket first to request for the Download Link. When I get the download link and tried it, it gives me the 403 error. Kindly try it yourself here on the live website here: https://cloudvid.gq/d/oab9xxgqz1fzpld/ It's perfectly working on local developement but not on live server.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone yeah. I'm basically using the free tier of AWS and just trying to learn how to use API by building test projects.

Comment: The error message is clear. Sorry. Again, need more detail to hazard a guess. [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: IP address white listing / restricting?

Answer (score 1):

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autonomous_system_(Internet)

TLDR: An ASN identifies a internet network operator. IP address blocks are assigned to ASNs.

This thing seems to be complaining that you're attempting to access it from [AS14618](https://bgp.he.net/AS14618) [Amazon] when it is expecting to be accessed from [AS9299](https://bgp.he.net/AS9299) [Philippine LDT].

Either you need to get the remote provider to allow access from Amazon, or you need to keep your website inside their approved network.